# Configure Eclipse for Phonegap build

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, build

I am new to Phonegap and have succesfully created my first app and compiled first on-line then set up phonegap, android SDK etc locally so I can build and run the app in the emulator using 'phonegap run android' at the command prompt (windows).

For an IDE I installed Eclipse and imported the project. I can now run the project from within Eclipse.

However I am really struggling with the Eclipse build. It's taken days already to solve all the problems and get to this stage but I've reached the point where I can't make progress although it would seem so simple.

The build project option is disabled. It turns on if I add something under 'Builders' under 'Configure Build Path...' but I have no idea what I should be doing here.

I can go back to the CMD prompt and build, refresh in Eclipse and run the modified version but this can't be the right way to do it?

I just need to tell Eclipse to 'phonegap build'. But how?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a project using PhoneGap it creates a Gradle based build which can be opened in [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) or [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). I recommend using Android Studio for PhoneGap projects.

Comment: Thank you. I have started to use Android Studio as suggested. This was great help http://www.codenutz.com/getting-started-phonegap-android-studio/.